# What is the interval for $\arg x$ when $z=ix^2$ and $\pi/2\le \arg z\le\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am a bit confused about this seemingly simple result arising from complex analysis. Let $\pi/2\le \arg z\le \pi$. Set $z=ix^2$, $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then $0\le \arg x\le \pi/2$. How is this correct and, if it is, how can I generalise it? For example, what is $\arg x$ if $\arg z\in\left[\pi/2,\pi\right]$ but $z=x^2$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=re^{i\theta_x}$, then $$z=ix^2=ir^2e^{i(2\theta_x)}=r^2e^{i(2\theta_x+\frac\pi2)}$$ since $i=e^{i\frac\pi2}$.

So we have $$\theta_z=2\theta_x+\frac \pi2 \implies \theta_x=\frac {\theta_z}{2}-\frac\pi4$$

Applying $\frac\pi2 \leq \theta_z \leq \pi$. we get $0\leq \theta_x\leq \frac \pi4$.

Answer (score 2):

You add angles when multiplying in complex analysis, which is doubling the angle in case of squaring.

Similarly, you rotate 90° anticlockwise when multiplying with $i$.

The operation $ix^2$ thus doubles the interior angle and rotates the new interval 90° anticlockwise.

You know that the end result is the second quadrant, from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$. Reversing the 90° rotation makes the interval cover the first quadrant, from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$; reversing the doubling of angles from squaring, you half the interval which so ranges from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

For your second problem, where there is no rotation, since $z=x^2$ in contrast to $z=ix^2$, your reverse engineering is done in one step, halfening the interior angle of the interval by halfening the value of the interval's upper bound.